# repeat until loop in lua

Tags: lua

What Am I doing wrong with my lua code?

```
local which

print("Type f to convert fahrenheit to celsius and c to convert celsius to fahrenheit")
which = io.read()
repeat
    if which=="f" then
        local c
        local f
        print("input your fahrenheit temperature")
        f = tonumber(io.read())
        c = (f-32)/1.8
        print(c)
    end

    elseif which=="c" then
        local ce
        local fa
        print("input your celsius temperature")
        c = tonumber(io.read())
        f = (c*1.8)+32
    end

    else do
    print("Type f to convert fahrenhiet to celsius and c to convert celsius to fahrenheit")
until which=="f" or which=="c"
```

Comment: Keeping consistent indentation keeps things more clear: indent your repeat body... This'll help you with lots of this type of errors (though not exactly this instance).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are closing your `if` block first. Remove the `end` statements which you have used to close `if` and `elseif` and put it just to close after `else`.

```
local which

print("Type f to convert fahrenheit to celsius and c to convert celsius to fahrenheit")
which = io.read()
repeat
    if which=="f" then
        local c
        local f
        print("input your fahrenheit temperature")
        f = tonumber(io.read())
        c = (f-32)/1.8
        print(c)

    elseif which=="c" then
        local ce
        local fa
        print("input your celsius temperature")
        c = tonumber(io.read())
        f = (c*1.8)+32

    else
        print("Type f to convert fahrenhiet to celsius and c to convert celsius to fahrenheit")
    end
until which=="f" or which=="c"
```

---

**P.S.**: This might lead you to infinite loop. You need to update `which` after every iteration inside the repeat until.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no `end` before `elseif`. There should also be no `end` before and no `do` after `else`. And there should be an `end` after the `else` part and before `until`:

```
repeat
  if ... then
    ...
  elseif ... then
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
until ...
```

Next time it would be helpful if you posted at least what your problem is (error message, unexpected output, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

```
local which
repeat
    print("Type f to convert fahrenheit to celsius and c to convert celsius to fahrenheit")
    which = io.read()
    if which=="f" then
        local c
        local f
        print("input your fahrenheit temperature")
        f = tonumber(io.read())
        c = (f-32)/1.8
        print(c)

    elseif which=="c" then
        local c
        local f
        print("input your celsius temperature")
        c = tonumber(io.read())
        f = (c*1.8)+32
        print(f)
    end
    print("do you want to play again? y/n?")
    antwort = io.read()


until antwort ~= "y"
```

Comment: Can you describe very briefly what is the problem?